# problem switching to client side compilation

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

I'm trying to switch to client-side compilation in Configuration->Advanced->Developer->Frontend Development Workflow however the option is disabled and I cant' select it. It says

`not available in production mode`

however I'm in developer mode from what I can see.

- in `app/etc/env.php` I have

`'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',`

- in `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show` the result is

`Current application mode: developer.`

- in .htaccess there is the line

`SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer`

- I've cleaned `generated/code` directory
- I've ran `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- I've set ownership/permissions to all folders and files

Any ideas what else I can try?

After further troubleshooting I can see in 
`vendor/magento/module-developer/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/WorkflowType.php`

```
if ($this->_appState->getMode() == \Magento\Framework\App\State::MODE_PRODUCTION)
```

returns `false` so I'm definitely NOT in production mode and `parent::render()` is called.

Afterwards in 
`vendor/magento/module-config/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php`

I can see $isCheckboxRequired is true and $element->getInherit() returns 1 so the field is disabled.

```
public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
{
    $isCheckboxRequired = $this->_isInheritCheckboxRequired($element);

    // Disable element if value is inherited from other scope. Flag has to be set before the value is rendered.
    if ($element->getInherit() == 1 && $isCheckboxRequired) {
        $element->setDisabled(true);
}
```

However I can't see from the field definition in system.xml why this field is impossible to edit for me.

Comment: Have you tried running bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: Yes I did, I also cleared the following folders var/cache, generated/metadata, generated/code, var/view_preprocessed, pub/static

Comment: hmm I not sure could it be set in the apache config file? /etc/apache2/sites-available/mage2.conf or something?

Comment: I checked all files related to configuration apache/nginx and there is no reference to the MAGE_MODE variable. I did add some troubleshooting info after stepping in through the code though.

Answer (score 0):

If this setting is disabled, this value was most likely hard-coded in the `app/etc/config.php` file. Look for the lines:

```
'front_end_development_workflow' => [
    'type' => 'server_side_compilation'
],
```

and remove them from the file.

You'll then need to import the new configuration by running:

```
bin/magento app:config:import
```

After reloading the page, the setting should no longer be disabled.